# WkWebView with adaptive width and height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, wkwebview

I need to create a WkWebView with adaptive size.(The size will mostly be fixed i.e 300 * 250 and sometimes it could have a dynamic height. It depends on the type of response I get from server)

The initial size of my WkWebView is 300 * 250.

To expand the WkWebView frame I calculate height from didFinish callback and updating the frame.

The problem with this solution is that WkWebview updates its frame twice and the user experience is not good.
Is there another way to do this?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
let height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
webView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: Double(height))
}
```

Comment: how about keeping the wkwebview hidden until you got the actual size.

Comment: @Bilal That is one approach which I have currently implemented. The downside of it is there is a lag in user experience. Am I missing some WKWebView feature that allows me to do so ?

Comment: How about adding a blocking view with a loading indicator? That view would then be removed when the didFinish callback completes and your webView is ready to go.

Comment: It would be better to evaluateJavaScript to get the document.body.scrollHeight and this can be done in document.readyState and then change the height and updateConstraints too.